# Storyboard breakdown

Tags: swift, storyboard, uistoryboard

I got a huge storyboard which needs to be breakdown into pieces. Now the first phase is breaking the introduction  step & login step into two storyboard. Either of these could be the very first page after starting the app. In my **Deployment info > Main interface = Main**, in this storyboard the login pages are there, I am struggling when the first page is introduction page, coz I have shifted those into new storyboard. Any suggesting how can I switch into multiple storyboard in the very beginning of the app ?

Comment: Since you have many controllers, wouldn’t be better to use nib files?

Comment: You can set rootviewcontroller equals to your first controller in appdelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: Its already a completed project with lots of viewController and nib files.I am not making any new viewController or nib file, just rearranging them into small storyboards

Comment: @AnjiMendpara nice suggestion, got to check if I missed that :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to do it programmatically within the `AppDelegate` when the app launches.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        // your login page logic
        let isLoginPage = false

        let storyboardName = isLoginPage ? "loginStoryboard" : "introductionStoryboard"
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

You can go further with more optimisation using a specific class to handle all navigation of your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `rootViewController` manually in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Navigation.NAV_LOGIN)
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```